# Render CONTENT with custom template

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-8.x

Is there a solution to only change the template of a contentelement selected by typoscript?

Like this:

```
lib.testelement = CONTENT
lib.testelement {
    renderObj {
        file = Path/to/my/template.html
    }
    table = tt_content
    select {
        pidInList = MyPid
        where = uid=MyUid
        max = 1
    }
}
```

I need the assigned variables from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Without the `renderObj` the default rendering is used for the selected record.
if you want to use a `renderObj` you have to define the complete rendering.
This could be a copy of the default rendering.
you problem: the rendering is dependent on the `CType` (and `list_type`) (so you might know the `CType` of that single CE).
So it becomes more and more complicated.

**Maybe you can use another solution:**
if you replace the fluid template from FSC for that kind of CE you want to use specially with a copy of the default fluid template.
in that copy you insert a condition `<f:if condition="{data.pid} == Mypid">` so you can do another rendering if this kind of CE came from your special page.

Answer (score 0):

renderObj must be an official cObject, so this should do the job

```
lib.testelement = CONTENT
lib.testelement {
    renderObj = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    renderObj {
        file = Path/to/my/template.html
    }
    table = tt_content
    select {
        pidInList = MyPid
        where = uid=MyUid
        max = 1
    }
}
```

See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html for other parameters of FLUIDTEMPLATE

To give integrators the option to expand the rendering without having to touch the FLUIDTEMPLATE itself, you could add a COA

```
lib.testelement = CONTENT
lib.testelement {
    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
        10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
        10.file = Path/to/my/template.html
    }
    table = tt_content
    select {
        pidInList = MyPid
        where = uid=MyUid
        max = 1
    }
}
```